# send email, changing sending address/ account depending on user

Tags: php, email

I have a locally used site for my work to create and send orders via email.

I would like the sending address to be changed depending on who is sending the email (can be identified by a previously set session variable). How can i do this?

for example if mark was to send a email it would be sent from  mark@companyname.com, and then if the user steve was to log on and send a email it would be sent via his email steve@companyname.com.

The main reason for wanting this is that that the recipient can see who has sent them the email, and will allow them to reply directly to the staff member. I have looked into setting from and reply addresses in the header but it seems unreliable

Comment: How are you setting the sender name now if not with headers?

Comment: Are you using php's mail function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php or PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below:

```
<?php

    $from = "someonelse@example.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

It will display from address to receipient like someonelse@example.com via domanin.com

Comment: Is this reliable though? Is it possible that certain email programs will it ignore this and when the receiver clicks reply it will send it to the servers email address opposed to the staff who sent the email (hope this makes sense, not sure quite how to word it)

Comment: There's no such thing as "server's email address" in the email headers. The only thing that can override `From:` part in the headers is `Reply-To:` and that isn't set if you don't set it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp) can do all this for you.

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
//etc
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Interesting - will look into it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just you need to use header with [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function :

For example you can use this function

```
<?php
        function sendMail($to,$subject,$msg,$from = DEFULT_FROM){
            // message
            $message = '
            <html>
            <head>

            </head>
            <body dir="rtl">
            <p align="right">'
            . $msg .
            '</p>


            </body>
            </html>
            ';

            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";

            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1256' . "\n";

            // Additional heade rs
            $headers .= "From: ".$from . "\n";
            //$headers .= 'Bcc: info@xxxx.co.uk' . "\n";

            // Mail it
            return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }


    ///// use 

    $message = " Hi World !";
    $subject= "My subject ";
    $from=$username@companyname.com /// change $username with your variable
    $to ="steve@companyname.com" ;

    /////// call function 
    $check = sendMail($to,$subject,$message ,$from);
    if($check){
    echo " Sent :) ";
    }
    else{

    echo " Not Sent :( ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cheers, although same concern as posted to Shiv below -  is it reliable

Comment: 90% of reviewers at Sourceforge think so: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/reviews/